# How to update the image uri of apprunner usinbg aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr, amazon-app-runner

I was trying to up[date the image uri of source in aws apprunner using below command.

```
  aws apprunner update-service --service-arn arn:aws:apprunner:us-east-1:*:service/next-js/* --source-configuration ImageRepository={clp-ui-qa,some-tag} --region us-east-1
```

but its not working

and giving me the below error

```
Unknown options: ImageRepository=some-tag
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS cli command for updating image for Apprunner

```
aws apprunner update-service \
    --service-arn <arn_apprunner_service> \
    --source-configuration '{
        "ImageRepository": {
            "ImageIdentifier": "<repository_url>:<image_tag>",
            "ImageRepositoryType": "ECR"
        }
    }' \
    --region eu-central-1
```

**NOTE :** ImageRepositoryType is mandatory option `ECR|ECR_PUBLIC`

**Expected Output :** json schema for the updated Apprunner service, with `"Status": "OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS"`

**Reference :** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apprunner/update-service.html